# Memgraph issues while creating credit card dedication system pymgclient error

Tags: memgraphdb

ERROR [4/9] RUN git clone https://github.com/memgraph/pymgclient /pymgclient &&   cd pymgclient &&   python3

Comment: Interesting, what exactly is the error? Could you please update the question with the error message and/or context in which the whole command is executed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.